# Another exercise on $L^p-$ spaces.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $1<p<\infty$, $f\in L^p(\mu)$ and $\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ a bounded sequence in $L^p(\mu)$. Moreover let $$\int_A f_nd\mu\to\int_A fd\mu$$ for $n\to\infty$ and for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$. Show that for all $g\in L^q(\mu)$ such that $1<q<\infty$ we have $$\int_{\Omega}f_ngd\mu\to\int_{\Omega}fgd\mu$$ such that $1/p+1/q=1$.

My thoughts: The thing confusing me the most, is that the exercise doesn't say anything about the measure of $\Omega$. How can I conclude from $A$ to whole $\Omega$ without (sigma)finiteness?

Since $f_n$ is bounded, I know $|f_n|\leq C$ - $C$ being some constant and since $f_n\in L^p(\mu)$ we also have $||f_n||_p\leq C$. I want to argue that $\int |(f_n-f)g|d\mu\leq (\int |(f_n-f)|^p)^{1/p}\cdot(\int|g|^qd\mu)^{1/q}$ using Hölder. I think I have most of the pieces required for the exercise but I'm unable to put them together.

Comment: Bounded in $L^p$ does not imply the functions are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Approximate $g$ in $L^q$ by linear combinations $h$ of indicator functions of sets.

$$\left|\int_\Omega (f_n - f) g \; d\mu\right| \le
\left| \int_\Omega (f_n - f) h \; d\mu\right| + \|f_n - f\|_p \|g - h\|_q $$